# looping through a file on 2 lines in shell

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have a file which looks like this:

```
>a
TCCACTCCACGC
>b
ACCTCCAG
```

I want to loop through the file in such a way that it takes into account 2 lines at a time i.e `>a` and its sequence and then I want to store those 2 lines in a variable and then further use my bioinformatics tools clustalomega

Some thing like this

```
for lines in test.fa; 
do 
    clustalo -i $capture -o outputfile; 
done
```

where capture variable first time when the loop goes has this format

```
>a
TCCACTCCACGC
```

then next time

```
>b
ACCTCCAG
```

How can I do this?

Comment: May I know the cause for it to be as down voted???

Answer (score 3):

To collect the two lines separated by a newline in a variable...

```
while read line1 && read line2
do
    bothlines=$line1$'\n'$line2
    do_something_with "$bothlines"
done < test.fa
```

(works with ksh, bash, zsh)

Comment: in this do_something_with "$bothlines" if I type echo $bothlines, it should give me 
>a
TCCACTCCACGC

and then

>b
ACCTCCAG

Is it right???

because In the output I get >a<space>TCCACTCCACGC

Comment: You will get the two lines separated by a newline, as you described your requirement. If you want it separated by a space instead then replace `$'\n'` by `" "`. If you want the newline but don't see it you probably forgot to keep the double quotes around the variable.